# arrayCollection In Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, symfony, arraycollection, jmsserializerbundle

i have this Action

```
public function testAction($array){
        /**
         * @var $array \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
         */
        return array(
            'array_like' => $array->slice(0,5),
          );
    }
```

that i render in my twig with

```
{{ render(controller("SNWallBundle:Wall:test" ,{ 'array': obj.spotted.spottedLike} )) }}
```

then i want to call testAction for slice to 5,10

with ajax call like

```
 $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: Routing.generate('test',{array:ARRAY COLLECTION !}),
                dataType: "json",
                beforeSend: function() {
                },
                success: function(msg) {
                    console.log("OK");
                },
                error: function(msg) {
                },
                complete :function( msg ) {
                }
            });
```

How can i do it? 
i have to use JMS Serializer?

Comment: Any particular reason you're not using JsonResponse? http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/introduction.html#creating-a-json-response

Comment: in controller caricaCommentoAction ? no...